# represent a xml on Swagger yaml

Tags: xml, yaml, swagger

I'm making a document on swagger editor, but I don't know how solve that..

What do I need to write in a YAML file to get this result?

```
<tag>
    <example Amount='100.00' NumberOfGuests='1'/>
    <example Amount='120.00' NumberOfGuests='2'/>
    <example Amount='140.00' NumberOfGuests='3'/>
</tag>
```

I tried to write "example" multiple times but an error appears:

> (YAML Syntax Error
>   Duplicated mapping key at line 621)

What do I need to do to represent the same tag multiple times with different values on the same attributes?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question.  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you'd do it like this:

```
definitions:
  Tag:
    xml:
      # use `tag` instead of `Tag` as the name
      name: tag
    properties:
      example:
        type: array
        items:
          $ref: '#/definitions/Example'
        xml:
          # don't wrap array
          wrapped: false
  Example:
    type: object
    properties:
      Amount:
        type: number
        format: float
        xml:
          # it's an attribute, not an element
          attribute: true
      NumberOfGuests:
        type: integer
        format: int32
        xml:
          attribute: true
```

Note the `xml` attributes to tell how to format the XML specific payload in JSON Schema.  More on that structure is found [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#xmlObject).

Comment: thanks @fehguy!
there's a way to define two  or more objects on default?